# Need to display a Confirmation Box on "Submit" Click of JQGrid Edit Dialog Box

Tags: jqgrid

I am working on a Requirement to Display a Confirmation Box when a User Selects a Row to Edit and Clicks "Submit" button in the Dialog Opens up for EditGridRow.

Code:

```
jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', id,
                    {
                        editCaption: "Edit App Settings",
                        bSubmit: "Submit",
                        bCancel: "Cancel",
                        bClose: "Close",
                        saveData: "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
                        bYes : "Yes",
                        bNo : "No",
                        bExit : "Cancel",
                        recreateForm:true,
                        closeAfterEdit:true,
                        closeOnEscape:true,
                        reloadAfterSubmit:false
                        //onclickSubmit:ConfirmEdit()//function(){confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit the Record?');}
                     }                         
                );
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an option called `checkOnSubmit` that sounds like it does what you are looking for. From the [jqGrid docs for Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing):

> **checkOnSubmit**
>
> This option work only in editing mode. If Set to true this option will work only when a submit button is clicked and if any data is changed in the form. If the data is changed a dilog message appear where the user is asked to confirm the changes or cancel it. Pressing cancel button of the new dialog will return to the form, but does not set the values to its original state.

Comment: @Justin...I just tried the checkOnSubmit option and it seems to be working. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Though one thing I couldn't understand is: Why the Dialog appears only when you modify some data and not when you do not modify it and Click "Submit"...!

Comment: @PrasadTilloo - If you do not modify any data on the form before clicking submit, nothing would be changed (at least in theory). So there is no need to prompt the user to confirm their changes since they have not made any.